# Android : What is the difference between View.inflate and getLayoutInflater().inflate?

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

What is the real difference between :

```
return context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.

and

```
return View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

> Inflate a view from an XML resource. This convenience method wraps the LayoutInflater class, which provides a full range of options for view inflation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are the same. The 2nd version is just a convenient and short method to do the task. If you see the source code of `View.inflate()` method, you find :

```
 /**
     * Inflate a view from an XML resource.  This convenience method wraps the {@link
     * LayoutInflater} class, which provides a full range of options for view inflation.
     *
     * @param context The Context object for your activity or application.
     * @param resource The resource ID to inflate
     * @param root A view group that will be the parent.  Used to properly inflate the
     * layout_* parameters.
     * @see LayoutInflater
     */
    public static View inflate(Context context, int resource, ViewGroup root) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return factory.inflate(resource, root);
    }
```

Which actually does the same job in the backend, the 1st method you mentioned does.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same and do same thing

In `View.java` class

```
public static View inflate(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, ViewGroup root) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return factory.inflate(resource, root);
    }
```

and `LayoutInflater.from(context)` return the `LayoutInflator` object. which is same as calling `getLayoutInflator()` method.

```
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (LayoutInflater == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
        }
        return LayoutInflater;
    }
```